# Handling larger tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, dataset

I am relatively new to Tensorflow and have been putting together some model training based on the tutorial I found on the ts website. I have been able to put together something functional that satisfies my preliminary requirements.

I am reading locally a csv files that provides some links towards images associated with labels written on the same csv row. My code roughly look like that:

```
def map_func(*row):
  img = process_img(img_filename)
  output = read(row)
  return img, output

dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(CSV_FILE, default_format, header=True)
dataset = dataset.map(map_func)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)
dataset = dataset.batch(NB_IMG)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

X, y = next(iter(dataset))

X_train, X_test = tf.split(X, split, axis=0)
y_train, y_test = tf.split(y, split, axis=0)

model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER, loss='mse')
model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

NB_IMG is the total number of images I have. EPOCHS is here arbitrary fixed to a given value (in general 20 or 40) and the split is a ratio applied on NB_IMG.

All my images are locally on my computer and with that code my GPU currently can manage up to 50000 images roughly. The training is failing with more images (GPU exhausted). I can understand that is due to the fact that I am reading the data all at once, but I am bit blocked to take the next step here to be able to manage a bigger dataset.

This part below is the one that need improvement I guess:

```
X, y = next(iter(dataset))
```

Could someone here help me to move forward and guide me towards some examples or snippets where I can train the model on a bigger dataset? I am a bit lost here for the next move and not sure where to focus in the ts documentation. I did not really find a clear example online that would suit my needs. How should I loop on different batches? How is coded the iterator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, can you give more details about the two functions `process_img` and `read`?

During my experiments, I have noticed that the `shuffle` function can be slow when you have a lot of data and the buffer size is big. Try to comment that line and check if it runs faster. If so, you can use `pandas` to load your CSV file and then shuffle it and use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`

Tensorflow has a great tool now to profile models and the dataset pipeline (https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras).

Answer (score 0):

`process_img` and `read` are very simple functions:

```
def process_img(filename):
  img = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  return tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
```

```
def read(row):
  return row[1]
```

The shuffle part of my code is slow but does not seem to be the cause of failure, I can remove it and shuffle the data directly from the csv. It seems to fail at the `X, y = next(iter(dataset))` line if the dataset is too big

Thanks for your suggestions to profile the code, I will give it a go. Is there any other possible approach to split and iterate among the dataset?